# Cannot update Android ADT using remote site or zip archive

Tags: android, adt

Android manual: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#InstallingADT

I have followed the steps in the Android manual to update and troubleshooting ADT, but all without success.

I cannot access Android SDK and AVD manager, as it says "Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences".
I downloaded the zip version to install it manually, but then I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.
```

I also tried installing new software using Eclipse with the website url: 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

But then a problem occurs:

> An error occurred while uninstalling session context
>   was:(profile=SDKProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall,
>   operand=[R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 -->
>   [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534,
>   action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
>   Error while loading manipulator. Error while loading manipulator.

I have Eclipse 3.6.2 installed on my macbook, with build id: M20110210-1200.
I installed a newer version of Eclipse, but was not able to open it. 
When I double clicked on the Eclipse program, it appears very shortly in the dock below and disappears after. Therefore I need to use the current Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

@Yanny try  downloading new version Juno.& then do the following steps.It worked fine for me
Help--> Install new Software-->Available software sites--> Click this site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
Make sure that *Show only software applicable to your environment* is clicked & install all of them.This will fix your problem. It worked well for me.But I am using Windows 7